# bash : Split file into chunks and aggregate field values

Tags: bash, unix, awk

Have a reference file - Collections.txt as below:

```
Name|Id|Course|...
Tom|111|PHY|...
Tommy|111|CHEM|...
.
.
Jim|222|PHY|...
Jimmy|222|CHEM?...
```

Corresponding to field "ID" there are other files, such as below:

```
ref_ID.gz
```

The format of file `ref_id.gz` is as below:

```
SNo,School,City,Count,...
12345,St Marys,NY,20,...
12345,St Agnes,NY,12,...
12345,St Aug,CA,23,...
54311,St Anthony,CA,32...
54311,St Agg,CA,9,...
```

The requirement is to fetch the ref_ID.gz file, which is basically the unique "ID" from the file Collections.txt. Then from the ref_ID.gz file separate out chunks based on the first column and then aggregate the below:

1. Sum of the field - Count for every "SNo" from the ref_id.gz file
2. Row count for every "SNo" having "City" as CA or NY

The expected output can be visualised as below:

For ref_111.gz, for SNo : 12345, NY = 2, CA = 1, Count = 55

Below is the code snippet I am using:

```sh
cut -d"|"-f2 Collections.txt | sort -n | uniq > uniq_ids.txt

while read -r line; do
  ny_city_count=`zcat ref_${line}.gz | awk -F',' '$3=="NY"{c3++}END{print c3}'`
  ca_city_count=`zcat ref_${line}.gz | awk -F',' '$3=="CA"{c3++}END{print c3}'`
  count_sum=`zcat ref_${line}.gz | awk -F',' '{sum+=$4} END {print sum}'`
done < uniq_ids.txt
```

Since I am not able to break the `ref_id.gz` file into chunks of rows having same first column "SNo", I am not able to get the exact city count and sum of count for the respective "SNo".

Answer (score 1):

Would you please try the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS= read -r id; do
    file="ref_${id}.gz"
    echo "$file"
    [[ -f "$file" ]] && zcat "$file" | awk -F, '
        FNR > 1 {
            sno[$1]++
            if ($3 == "CA") ca[$1]++
            else if ($3 == "NY") ny[$1]++
            count[$1]+=$4
        }
        END {
            for (i in sno)
                printf("  SNo = %s, NY = %d, CA = %d, count = %d\n", i, ny[i], ca[i], count[i])
        }
    '
done < <(tail -n +2 Collections.txt | cut -d"|" -f2 | sort -n | uniq)
```

where the input files are:

Collections.txt

```
Name|Id|Course|...
Tom|111|PHY|...
Tommy|111|CHEM|...
```

ref_111.gz (compressed)

```
SNo,School,City,Count,...
12345,St Marys,NY,20,...
12345,St Agnes,NY,12,...
12345,St Aug,CA,23,...
54311,St Anthony,CA,32...
54311,St Agg,CA,9,...
```

Result:

```
ref_111.gz
  SNo = 54311, NY = 0, CA = 2, count = 41
  SNo = 12345, NY = 2, CA = 1, count = 55
```